# Juntar projetos Angular

Tags: angular

criei vários projetos angular simulando faces de um sistema, ex: projeto estoque, projeto financeiro e etc. E agora me surgiu uma duvida, eu ia fazer um sistema de login único que iria verificar quem é o usuário e direciona-lo para o projeto que tem acesso. Gostaria de saber existe uma maneira adequada de fazer? Pensei em criar um novo projeto, fazer uma verificação no login e depois ir criando componentes, e copiar e colocar dos projetos anteriores.

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira nesse caso é trabalhar com autenticação JWT. Essa autenticação não usaria as sessões gravadas e assim poderia ser interoperável entre as aplicações:

1. O app de login valida o usuário e gera o JWT de autenticação com um tempo de expiração, por segurança.
2. Baseado na regra de acesso do usuário, o app de login redirecionaria para o app do setor.
3. O app do setor, que é independente, receberia esse JWT e o validaria, sendo válido, usaria esse JWT como chave para todas as requisições ao backend/API